# Why ChoiceChip returning null value?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am developing a Barber Booking App. In done_services_screen I added Wrap() function of ChoiceChip. It is loading service list completely. However, I am not able to select services and due to that 'FINISH' button is showing disable.
Here is the code:

done_services_screen

```
class DoneService extends ConsumerWidget {
  GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> scaffoldKey = GlobalKey();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, watch) {
    //When refresh, clear servicesSelected, because ChipChoices don't hold state
    context.read(selectedServices).state.clear();
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        key: scaffoldKey,
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
        backgroundColor: Color(0xFFDFDFDF),
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Done Services'),
          backgroundColor: Color(0xFF383838),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
              child: FutureBuilder(
                future: getDetailBooking(
                    context, context.read(selectedTimeSlot).state),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting)
                    return Center(
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                    );
                  else {
                    var bookingModel = snapshot.data as BookingModel;
                    return Card(
                      elevation: 8,
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            Row(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                CircleAvatar(
                                  child: Icon(Icons.account_box_rounded,
                                      color: Colors.white),
                                  backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                                ),
                                SizedBox(
                                  width: 30,
                                ),
                                Column(
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: [
                                    Text('${bookingModel.customerName}',
                                        style: GoogleFonts.robotoMono(
                                            fontSize: 22,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                                    Text('${bookingModel.customerPhone}',
                                        style: GoogleFonts.robotoMono(
                                            fontSize: 18)),
                                  ],
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                            Divider(
                              thickness: 2,
                            ),
                            Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                              children: [
                                Consumer(builder: (context, watch, _) {
                                  var servicesSelected =
                                      watch(selectedServices).state;
                                  var totalPrice = servicesSelected
                                      .map((item) => item.price)
                                      .fold(
                                          0.0,
                                          (value, element) =>
                                              double.parse(value.toString()) +
                                              element);
                                  return Text(
                                    'Price \$${context.read(selectedBooking).state.totalPrice == 0 ? totalPrice : context.read(selectedBooking).state.totalPrice}',
                                    style: GoogleFonts.robotoMono(fontSize: 22),
                                  );
                                }),
                                context.read(selectedBooking).state.done
                                    ? Chip(
                                        label: Text('Finished'),
                                      )
                                    : Container()
                              ],
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  }
                },
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                child: FutureBuilder(
                    future: getServices(context),
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting)
                        return Center(
                          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                        );
                      else {
                        var services = snapshot.data as List<ServiceModel>;
                        return Consumer(builder: (context, watch, _) {
                          var servicesWatch = watch(selectedServices).state;
                          return SingleChildScrollView(
                              child: Column(
                            children: [
                              Wrap(
                                children: services.map((e) => Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4),
                                    child: ChoiceChip(
                                        selected: context.read(selectedServices).state.contains(e),
                                        selectedColor: Colors.blue,
                                        label: Text('${e.name}'),
                                        labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                        backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
                                        onSelected: (isSelected){
                                          var list = context.read(selectedServices).state;
                                          if (isSelected)
                                            {
                                              list.add(e);
                                              context.read(selectedServices).state = list;
                                            }
                                          else{
                                            list.remove(e);
                                            context.read(selectedServices).state = list;
                                          }
                                      },
                                    ),
                                )).toList(),
                              ),
                              Container(
                                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                                child: ElevatedButton(
                                  onPressed:
                                      context.read(selectedBooking).state.done
                                          ? null
                                          : servicesWatch.length > 0
                                              ? () => finishService(context)
                                              : null,
                                  child: Text(
                                    'FINISH',
                                    style: GoogleFonts.robotoMono(),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              )
                            ],
                          ));
                        });
                      }
                    }),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  finishService(BuildContext context) {
    var batch = FirebaseFirestore.instance.batch();
    var barberBook = context.read(selectedBooking).state;

    var userBook = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('User')
        .doc('${barberBook.customerPhone}')
        .collection('Booking_${barberBook.customerId}')
        .doc(
            '${barberBook.barberId}_${DateFormat('dd_MM_yyyy').format(DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(barberBook.timeStamp))}');
    Map<String, dynamic> updateDone = new Map();
    updateDone['done'] = true;
    updateDone['services'] =
        convertServices(context.read(selectedServices).state);
    updateDone['totalPrice'] = context
        .read(selectedServices)
        .state
        .map((e) => e.price)
        .fold(
            0.0,
            (previousValue, element) =>
                double.parse(previousValue.toString()) + element);

    batch.update(userBook, updateDone);
    batch.update(barberBook.reference!, updateDone);

    batch.commit().then((value) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(scaffoldKey.currentContext!)
          .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text('Process Success')))
          .closed
          .then((v) => Navigator.of(context).pop());
    });
  }
}
```

service_model

```
class ServiceModel {
  String name = '';
  String? docId = '';
  double price = 0;

  ServiceModel({required this.name, required this.price});

  ServiceModel.fromJson(Map<String,dynamic> json) {
    name = json['name'];
    price = json['price'] == null ? 0 : double.parse(json['price'].toString());

  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson(){
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['name'] = this.name;
    data['price'] = this.price;
    return data;
  }
}
```

booking_model

```
class BookingModel {
  String? docId = '', services = '';
  String barberId = '',
      barberName = '',
      cityBook = '',
      customerId = '',
      customerName = '',
      customerPhone = '',
      salonAddress = '',
      salonId = '',
      salonName = '',
      time = '';

  double totalPrice=0;
  bool done = false;
  int slot = 0, timeStamp = 0;

  DocumentReference? reference;

  BookingModel(
      {this.docId,
      required this.barberId,
      required this.barberName,
      required this.cityBook,
      required this.customerId,
      required this.customerName,
      required this.customerPhone,
      required this.salonAddress,
      required this.salonId,
      required this.salonName,
      this.services,
      required this.time,
      required this.done,
      required this.slot,
      required this.totalPrice,
      required this.timeStamp});

  BookingModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    barberId = json['barberId'];
    barberName = json['barberName'];
    cityBook = json['cityBook'];
    customerId = json['customerId'];
    customerName = json['customerName'];
    customerPhone = json['customerPhone'];
    salonAddress = json['salonAddress'];
    salonName = json['salonName'];
    salonId = json['salonId'];
    services = json['services'];
    time = json['time'];
    done = json['done'] as bool;
    slot = int.parse(json['slot'] == null ? '-1' : json['slot'].toString());
    totalPrice = double.parse(
        json['totalPrice'] == null ? '0' : json['totalPrice'].toString());
    timeStamp = int.parse(
        json['timeStamp'] == null ? '0' : json['timeStamp'].toString());
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['barberId'] = this.barberId;
    data['barberName'] = this.barberName;
    data['cityBook'] = this.cityBook;
    data['customerId'] = this.customerId;
    data['customerName'] = this.customerName;
    data['customerPhone'] = this.customerPhone;
    data['salonAddress'] = this.salonAddress;
    data['salonName'] = this.salonName;
    data['salonId'] = this.salonId;
    data['time'] = this.time;
    data['done'] = this.done;
    data['slot'] = this.slot;
    data['timeStamp'] = this.timeStamp;
    return data;
  }
}
```

services_ref

```
Future<List<ServiceModel>> getServices(BuildContext context) async{
  var services = List<ServiceModel>.empty(growable: true);
  CollectionReference serviceRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Services');
  QuerySnapshot snapshot = await serviceRef.where(
    context.read(selectedSalon).state.docId!, isEqualTo: true
  ).get();
  snapshot.docs.forEach((element) {
    final data = element.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
    var serviceModel = ServiceModel.fromJson(data);
    serviceModel.docId = element.id;
    services.add(serviceModel);
  });
  return services;
}
```

all_salon_ref

```
Future<BookingModel> getDetailBooking(BuildContext context, int timeSlot) async{
  CollectionReference userRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('AllSalon')
      .doc(context.read(selectedCity).state.name)
      .collection('Branch')
      .doc(context.read(selectedSalon).state.docId)
      .collection('Barber')
      .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
      .collection(DateFormat('dd_MM_yyyy').format(context.read(selectedDate).state));
  DocumentSnapshot snapshot = await userRef.doc(timeSlot.toString()).get();
  if (snapshot.exists)
    {
      var bookingModel = BookingModel.fromJson(json.decode(json.encode(snapshot.data())));
      bookingModel.docId = snapshot.id;
      bookingModel.reference = snapshot.reference;
      context.read(selectedBooking).state = bookingModel;
      return bookingModel;
    }
  else
    return BookingModel(
      barberId: '',
      barberName: '',
      cityBook: '',
      customerName: '',
      customerPhone: '',
      salonAddress: '',
      salonId: '',
      salonName: '',
      time: '',
      done: false,
      slot: 0,
      timeStamp: 0,
      customerId: '',
      totalPrice: 0);
}

Future<List<CityModel>> getCities() async {
  var cities = new List<CityModel>.empty(growable: true);
  var cityRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('AllSalon');
  var snapshot = await cityRef.get();
  snapshot.docs.forEach((element) {
    cities.add(CityModel.fromJson(element.data()));
  });
  return cities;
}

Future<List<SalonModel>> getSalonByCity(String cityName) async {
  var salons = new List<SalonModel>.empty(growable: true);
  var salonRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('AllSalon')
      .doc(cityName.replaceAll(' ', ''))
      .collection('Branch');
  var snapshot = await salonRef.get();
  snapshot.docs.forEach((element) {
    var salon = SalonModel.fromJson(element.data());
    salon.docId = element.id;
    salon.reference = element.reference;
    salons.add(salon);
  });
  return salons;
}

Future<List<BarberModel>> getBarbersBySalon(SalonModel salon) async {
  var barbers = new List<BarberModel>.empty(growable: true);
  var barberRef = salon.reference!.collection('Barber');
  var snapshot = await barberRef.get();
  snapshot.docs.forEach((element) {
    var barber = BarberModel.fromJson(element.data());
    barber.docId = element.id;
    barber.reference = element.reference;
    barbers.add(barber);
  });
  return barbers;
}

Future<List<int>> getTimeSlotOfBarber(
    BarberModel barberModel, String date) async {
  List<int> result = new List<int>.empty(growable: true);
  var bookingRef = barberModel.reference!.collection(date);
  QuerySnapshot snapshot = await bookingRef.get();
  snapshot.docs.forEach((element) {
    result.add(int.parse(element.id));
  });
  return result;
}

Future<bool> checkStaffOfThisSalon(BuildContext context) async {
  DocumentSnapshot barberSnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('AllSalon')
      .doc('${context.read(selectedCity).state.name}')
      .collection('Branch')
      .doc(context.read(selectedSalon).state.docId)
      .collection('Barber')
      .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid) //Compare uid of this staff
      .get();
  return barberSnapshot.exists;
}

Future<List<int>> getBookingSlotOfBarber(
    BuildContext context, String date) async {
  var barberDocument = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('AllSalon')
      .doc('${context.read(selectedCity).state.name}')
      .collection('Branch')
      .doc(context.read(selectedSalon).state.docId)
      .collection('Barber')
      .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid); //Compare uid of this staff
  List<int> result = new List<int>.empty(growable: true);
  var bookingRef = barberDocument.collection(date);
  QuerySnapshot snapshot = await bookingRef.get();
  snapshot.docs.forEach((element) {
    result.add(int.parse(element.id));
  });
  return result;
}
```

In debug, I checked service list is getting updated but widget tree is not getting refreshed according to that. Also, the isSelected method always returns a null. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my own problem by changing these lines:

This line:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context, watch) {
```

replaced by this:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context, ScopedReader watch) {
```

And these lines:

```
Wrap(
                            children: services.map((e) => Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4),
                                child: ChoiceChip(
                                    selected: context.read(selectedServices).state.contains(e),
                                    selectedColor: Colors.blue,
                                    label: Text('${e.name}'),
                                    labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                    backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
                                    onSelected: (isSelected){
                                      var list = context.read(selectedServices).state;
                                      if (isSelected)
                                        {
                                          list.add(e);
                                          context.read(selectedServices).state = list;
                                        }
                                      else{
                                        list.remove(e);
                                        context.read(selectedServices).state = list;
                                      }
                                  },
                                ),
                            )).toList(),
                          )
```

replaced by those:

```
Wrap(
                              children: services.map((e) => Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4),
                                child: ChoiceChip(
                                  selected: servicesWatch.contains(e),
                                  selectedColor: Colors.blue,
                                  label: Text('${e.name}'),
                                  labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                  backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
                                  onSelected: (isSelected){
                                    var list = servicesWatch.toList();
                                    if (isSelected) {
                                      list.add(e);
                                    } else {
                                      list.remove(e);
                                    }
                                    context.read(selectedServices).state = list;
                                  },
                                ),
                              )).toList(),
                            ),
```